# XmlSchema Compatibility

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I'm using v4.1.8.8

I have a number of individual rules xml documents that I want to combine into a rule set.
After combining them I need to do some modification so it would be a lot easier of all of the elements were in the same namespace.

Some are using the namespace http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41 and some are using http://rule.codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/4

If I change all of the http://rule.codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/4 namespaces to http://codeeffects.com/schemas/rule/41 will they be backwards compatible? It doesn't appear that any Schema Validation is performed when executing rules so I'm guessing this won't be an issue, but it never hurts to check

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't be an issue provided all your rules use the same source object